# Unobtrusive validation fires on 'Must be a number' when it IS a number

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, unobtrusive-validation

I have a modal view with 2 drop downs, the user selects one or the other.  After the user makes a selection, a third dropdown is populated dynamically with a Get call.  Finally, a field is populated by slicing the value out of the 'GET' returned value.

Properties involved are GID (string), SeedId (int?) and BinId(int)

The 2 drop downs are for GID and SeeId.  Usually GID is actually numeric, but occasionally it is alpha or alphanumeric, hence the string type.  Even if the user is not selecting a SeedId from the dropdown, I need it to save the entity.

The problem I am having is when the user selects from the GID ddl and the value is alpha or alphanumeric, I get an error "SeedID must be a number".  This make no sense to me because SeedId is ALWAYS a number, regardless of the chosen GID.

Now for some code:

The model:

```
    public int? SeedId { get; set; 
    public string GID { get; set; }
    public int BinId { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> SeedOptionList { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> BinOptionList { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GIDOptionList { get; set; }
```

The view code:

```
<div id="container-gid-search" class="hidden">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.GID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.GID, Model.GIDOptionList, "Select GID...", new { @class = "form-control auto-complete" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.GID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
<div id="container-seed-search" class="hidden">
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SeedId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SeedId, Model.SeedOptionList, "",new { @class = "form-control auto-complete" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SeedId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.BinId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.BinId, new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.KGBalance, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.BinId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
</div>
```

The jquery that populate the bin list and populates the seed id field for saving:

```
$("#GID").on("change", function () {
    var gid = $(this).val();
    $("#BinId").empty();
    $.get({
        url: binUrl,
        data: { gid: gid},
        success: function (response) {
            $.each(response, function (index, item) {
                $("#BinId").append($('<option value="' + item.Value + '">' + item.Text + '</option>'));
            });

            //Pull the kilo value out of the selected bin and put it in the balance window.
            $("#KGBalance").val(SliceDecimalFromString($("#BinId option:selected").text()));

            //Grab the seedid and put it in the SeedId fields.
            var seedId = ExtractDecimalFromString($("#BinId option:selected").text(), '# ');
            $("input[name='SeedId']").val(seedId);
            $('#SeedId').val(seedId);

            var balance = $("#KGBalance").val() - $("#KGExtracted").val();
            $("#KGBalanceCheck").val(balance);
        }
    })
})



$("#BinId").on("change", function () {
    $("#KGBalance").val(SliceDecimalFromString($("#BinId option:selected").text()));

    if ($("#GID").val() !== "") {
        //Grab the seedid and put it in the SeedId fields.
        var seedId = ExtractDecimalFromString($("#BinId option:selected").text(), '# ');
        $("input[name='SeedId']").val(seedId);
        $('#SeedId').val(seedId);
    }
    //Do some other stuff that is unrelated
})

function ExtractDecimalFromString(stringIn, delimiter) {
    var kgString = stringIn;
    var idx = kgString.indexOf(delimiter);
    var strOut = kgString.substr(idx + 2);

    var intOut = parseInt(strOut);
    return intOut;
}
```

If I change SeedId in the model to a string, it works fine.  I don't know why the selected GID being alphanumeric makes a difference but that is the only time the error occurs.

Note:  I am using this bootstrap style combobox script on the SeedId select list: https://github.com/danielfarrell/bootstrap-combobox.  I mention it because it changes the rendered html of the drop downs by adding a hidden SeedId field with a name but no ID, which is why the jquery script puts the Seedid in a named field and an ID field.

Here is the actual rendered HTML.  The error I am getting is from the select list, "Seed Ref must be a number"

```
<div class="form-group">
   <label class="control-label" for="SeedId">Seed Ref:</label>
   <div class="combobox-container"> <input type="hidden" class="do-not-ignore" name="SeedId" value="9608"> 
       <div class="input-group"> 
            <input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="SeedIdundefined" placeholder="" class="form-control auto-complete"> 
            <span class="input-group-addon dropdown-toggle" data-dropdown="dropdown"><span class="caret"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></span> 
        </div> 
    </div>
    <select class="form-control auto-complete" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Seed Ref: must be a number." id="SeedId" style="display: none;">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="10439">10439</option>
        <option value="10438">10438</option>
        <option value="10437">10437</option>
        <option value="10436">10436</option>
    ...
    </select>
<span class="field-validation-valid text-danger" data-valmsg-for="SeedId" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
</div>
```

I'm also wondering why it is triggering validation when the SeedId is a nullable int.

Comment: `parseInt(strOut)` can throw `NaN`... Which is not a number, obviously. Console log your values. ;)

Comment: Louys - It was doing it before I added the parse to the function, which I added to try to fix this issue.  Just to make sure I double checked and it always logs a number.